# Trying to fill a cell with pandas with None and/or none but return a string

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I'm trying to use Python `3.11` and pandas `2.0.1` to automate a process in work that needs to be an `.xlsx` file, but I'm facing some issues. I developed the following function:

```
def add_nan_rows(df, column):
    new_rows = []
    previous_value = None

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        current_value = row[column]

        if previous_value is not None and current_value != previous_value:
            x = []
            for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
                x.append(None)
            new_row = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x)], columns=df.columns)
            new_rows.append(dict(new_row))

        new_rows.append(dict(row))
        previous_value = current_value
        
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns = df.columns)
    return new_df
```

It isn't the most elegant but kinda works in exception that in place of the nothing we spected with `None`-type variables, but it returned to me a string.

I also tried to substitute None with `np.nan` or `np.NaN` and all returned the following string:

```
0   NaN
Name: NUM_DOCUMENTO, dtype: float64
```

I also tried to not use a list, but put it directly in the dataframe, but didn't matter.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can *fix/adjust* your custom `func` this way :

```
def add_nan_rows(df, column):
    new_rows = []
    previous_value = None

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        current_value = row[column]

        if previous_value is not None and current_value != previous_value:
            new_rows.append(pd.Series([""] * len(df.columns), index=df.columns, name=""))

        new_rows.append(row)
        previous_value = current_value
    
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=df.columns)

    return new_df
```

Another variant with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
def add_nan_rows(df, column):
    new_df = (
        df.groupby(column, sort=False, group_keys=False)
            .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g, pd.DataFrame("", columns=df.columns, index=[""])]))
            .iloc[:-1]
    )
    return new_df
```

Test/Output :

```
out = add_nan_rows(df, "DUMMY_COL")
​
print(out)

  NUM_DOCUMENTO DUMMY_COL
0             1       foo
1             1       foo
                         
2             2       bar
                         
3             2       baz
4             3       baz
                         
5             3       qux
```

Excel view :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "NUM_DOCUMENTO": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "DUMMY_COL": ["foo", "foo", "bar", "baz", "baz", "qux"]}
)
```

Comment: I will try it, but it seems that will give another problem in the future, once that I need to do some calculations with it and I think "" will be seen as a string. However, I solve it doing in another way, by not using the data frame first and then transforming to a dictionary, but to iterating directly into one.

Comment: I choosed the *empty string* as a filling value for the index and the values as well of the added row just for visual purposes. Feel free to put whatever kind of value you want. And regarding your first point, sorry I can say nothing because I ignore what you intend to do with your new dataframe afterwards except this : *"... to automate a process in work that needs to be a `.xlsx` file."*

Comment: No problem @Timeless that give me insights for others steps in my project!